# How to call a function when instances are being dynamically created?

Tags: python

I'm a Java newbie, transitioning into Python and I've been trying to develop a simplistic market-like interaction between companies and investors. Basically, there are 100 companies and 100 investors been created dynamically with random values at initialization.

```
class Company:
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor for the Company object """
        self.id: str = uuid.uuid4().hex
        self.shares_num = random.randint(500, 1000)
        self.share_price = Decimal(random.randint(10, 100))

class Investor:
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor for the Investor object """
        self.id_inv: str = uuid.uuid1().hex
        self.budget: Decimal = random.randint(50_000, 100_000)
        self.acq_shares = 0

    def sell_shares(self):
        trade = self.budget - Company.get_share_price
        Company.get_shares_num -= 1
        self.acq_shares += 1
        self.set_budget = trade
        return self
```

The function sell_shares() performs the actual sale, i.e. makes the trade between the investor's money and the company's shares.

The companies and investors are then placed into a list with their ID and a dict with share's data for companies and budget's for investors.

```
# dynamic instances of Companies and Investors
comp = [Company() for _ in range(10)]
companies = {c.id: c for c in comp}

inv = [Investor() for _ in range(10)]
investors = {i.id_inv: i for i in inv}
```

The problem is when I call the sell_shares() method `Investors.sell_shares` neither the instances of companies or shares are affected. I don't really see anything wrong, apart from the fact that it isn't working.
Any suggestions on how I could try and fix this?

Thanks a million :)

P.S.: I'm using Python 3.8.2 with standard libraries.

Comment: Please correct the code indentation, and move the `trade()` function to wherever it's actually located in the code.

Comment: done @jarmod :) Thanks

Comment: Why does your `trade()` code use `inv[0]` and `comp[0]`? Instead, you should use `self` to refer to 'this investor' and pass in the relevant company object to the trade method as a `comp` parameter. It's not always going to be `comp[0]` that is traded.

Comment: No, it isn't. That was me trying to understand how Python passes values and mocking trading between the first Company and Investor in the list. It didn't work, though.
Also, the fact that I'm using getters and setters (due to price change, another app requirement) changes the 'self' there, no?
I've just tested swapping it and the output was "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'self'". I'm just really not sure how to make the class instances interact.

Comment: What is `inv.self.get_budget` supposed to do? `inv` is a list of 10 investors.

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 5. Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the biggest source of your pain is your use of mutable global variables inside of a class method. Please don't do that. Every time you do, somewhere, a baby kitten dies.

You could fix this problem quite easily by making trade() accept a keyword argument for a company, and then just operate using self (referring to that particular investor), and the keyword argument, (referring to a particular instance of a company). Don't try to access all the investors and companies at once, being that your method only depends on one of each.

```
import uuid
import random
from decimal import Decimal

class Company:
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor for the Company object """
        self.id: str = uuid.uuid4().hex
        self.shares_num = random.randint(500, 1000)
        self.share_price = Decimal(random.randint(10, 100))

class Investor:
    def __init__(self):
        """ Constructor for the Investor object """
        self.id: str = uuid.uuid1().hex
        self.budget: Decimal = random.randint(50000, 100000)
        self.acq_shares = 0

    def trade(self, company):
        trading = self.budget - company.share_price
        company.share_price -= 1
        self.acq_shares += 1

        # this equation is wrong, but I'm not sure entirely what you want to do here
        # this is equivalent to -company.share_price
        company.share_price = trading - self.budget

        self.budget = trading
        return self.id, self.budget
```

Note that this also removes any need to create `get_share_price()` or `get_budget()` methods.

If, somehow, I've misunderstood your setup, and your trade function *does* depend on *all* investors and *all* companies at once, then don't make it a class method. Make it a regular function, outside of a class, where it takes two arguments like so `def trade(investors, companies):`, because in that case, it doesn't have to do with that single class instance of investor.

You can test out your classes like so:

```
# Generate companies and investors
comp = [Company() for _ in range(10)]
companies = {c.id: c for c in comp} # <-- not sure what this is used for

inv = [Investor() for _ in range(10)]
investors = {i.id: i for i in inv} # <-- not sure what this is used for

# Select an investor and a company
some_investor = inv[random.randint(0,9)]
some_company = comp[random.randint(0,9)]

# Make a trade
some_investor.trade(some_company)

print(some_company.share_price) # prints a negative number
```

Note that your current formula for share price seems very wrong to me, being that it's equivalent to `self.budget - company.share_price - self.budget`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I updated the question before seeing your answer so the method is changed but your suggestion on using companies and investors as arguments has blown my newbie-mind. It's actually simpler than I imagined. No more mutable variables inside of a class method, I swear.
The line `investors = {i.id: i for i in inv}` declares a dictionary where ID is the key and {budget , acquired_shares} are is the data for each. I needed a list of all interactive instances for debugging purposes.
And, you are 100% right, my trade() algorithm looks like a blood bath. Thank you for all!

Comment: No problem. You can also pass variables into your `__init__(self)` method too. You could do something like `__init__(self, id, budget, shares): self.id = id; self.budget = budget; self.shares = shares`, and then instead of using random variables, you could declare the budgets and shares whenever you create an Investor() object by doing something like `some_investor = Investor(some_id, 76543, 0)`

Comment: The trade() method does not depend on _all_ companies and investors. But it's part of the requirements that trade() keeps trading until there is no more money to buy or shares to sell on the market. You reckon a nested for (complexity ouch, I know) would do it? <br/> Also, the `get_share_price()` method is due to a price update that will happen to companies every time they sell 10 shares to any investor, the share_price` will double. I intend to use a [moderator pattern] (https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator/python/1) for that. <br/> Again, thank you for your help. You're a star!

Comment: And I'd love to individually assign values for each company and investor but I need 100 of each after all and that code would not be DRY. I initially implemented a constructor/initializer with those attributes, but failed to assign random values to them. Tried using setters but they work very differently from Java and the entire thing became a frustrating mess with setters generating new random values every time I called an attribute. Man, being a newbie is hard...! :/

Comment: I would make a separate function (or method) that does continued trading (you could call it `make_trades` or `trade_all` or something), and I would use a single while loop that ensures money and shares are available, rather than a nested for loop. In general, composing a bunch of smaller, simpler functions (or methods) is much better than trying to do everything all at once in one big function.

Comment: This is DRY: `ids = [uuid.uuid4.hex() for _ in range(100)]; budgets = [random.randint(50000,100000) for _ in range(100)]; inv = [Investors(id, budget, 0) for (id, budget) in zip(ids, budgets)]`

Comment: Thank you times infinity. It's not the first time I get the feedback that I need to work on the modularity of my programs. Truly appreciate your help, though. I feel like I will be able to finish this app now :)